# How to sort a PHP array and using the same index for each element?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
numbers = array(
                 "1"=>2
                 "2"=>5
                 "3"=>1
                 "4"=>12

);
```

if I used sort(numbers) the array will become

```
numbers = array(
                 "1"=>1
                 "2"=>2
                 "3"=>5
                 "4"=>12

);
```

the indexes still in same places just sort the numbers
I want to move  the indexes also like the following:

```
numbers = array(
                 "3"=>1
                 "1"=>2
                 "2"=>5
                 "4"=>12

);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the [`asort`](https://www.php.net/asort) in this context.

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their
> correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is
> used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element
> order is significant.

```
<?php
$numbers = array(1=>2,2=>5,3=>1,4=>12);
asort($numbers);
print_r($numbers);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [3] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [4] => 12
)
```